# Retrieving info from database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm going to retrieve information from a database using LINQ but I don't know why I'm getting this error:

> Invalid object name 'Retriveinfos'.

My class is here:

```
[Table (Name="Retriveinfos")]
public class Retriveinfo
{
        [Column]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

and then using this line of code to connect and retrieving information:

```
DataContext dcon = new DataContext(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=F:\Second_School_project\Review_Site\Review_Site\App_Data\ReviewDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
Table<Retriveinfo> Retriveinfos = dcon.GetTable<Retriveinfo>();

var c = from d in Retriveinfos
        where d.Id == 1
        select new { d.Name, d.LastName };

foreach (var a in c)
    Response.Write(a.Name.ToString() + " " + a.LastName.ToString());
```

Comment: What line gives you that error?

Comment: Maybe you didn't add the proper `using` for the *link-to-sql* assembly.

Comment: Just as a side-note: you should spell it **retrieve** (not retrive) - that would be the correct spelling of that word in English

Comment: sorry marc_s you say right, the error is in foreach statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Retriveinfos is a table in your database not a class you may need to use something like the entity framework to create classes to represent you tables before you can do something like the above

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you type the dcon.xxx
At that moment you should get intellisense and you get the right names.

Futhermore, there is no need to do the GetTable, you can just do it like this

```
var c = from d in dcon.Retriveinfos  
where d.Id == 1         
select new { d.Name, d.LastName };  

foreach (var a in c)   
{ ... }
```

By the way, if your ID is indeed unique you can do this:

```
var c = dcon.Retriveinfos.SingleOrDefault(s=>s.id == 1)
```

And you can also skip your foreach in that case

Comment: i did it but i take this error:Error 1 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext' does not contain a definition for 'Retriveinfo' and no extension method 'Retriveinfo' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) F:\Second_School_project\Review_Site\Review_Site\Default.aspx.cs 33 36 Review_Site

Comment: Are you using a generic datacontext or your projectspecific datacontext??

Comment: Thank you, i'm changing this line of code [Table (Name="Retriveinfos")]
 to [Table] and the problem was solved but it is a right way to connect to database for inserting deleting and updating i know i should to use ConfigurationManager instead of putting connection string directly into DataContext.